# Why migration fails but compilation doesn't when consuming scoped services in singleton services in NET 5?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-5

Some background information first. My project had been done in NET Core 3.1. I created and applied migrations with no issues. After updating the project to NET 5, I started getting the `Cannot consume scoped service from singleton` error.

The situation was caused by having a scoped `DbContext` (its default lifetime) and trying to use it with singleton data services (by passing a `DbContext` as a parameter to the data service constructor).

I know why that happens, and how to deal with it, but I wanted to understand why it worked (both for adding migrations as well as compiling and running the app) in NET Core 3.1, while in NET 5 it *still compiles and runs*, but I cannot add migrations without passing a scope rather than the `DbContext` itself on the dataService. Has it been changed with the NET version?